# web based interpreter for language R

Tags: r, web, interpreter

I am looking for a web based interpreter for the language R.
To be more precise , i am looking for a IDE like http://codepad.org/  where i can provide the code and the server should execute and provide me with the output.

I went through applications like Rapache but then they don't fit my requirement as they are not made to accept code from client , execute it and provide the result.

In short , i could find web application which takes input from the user , execute a specific R script and then place the output in a neatly formated way but not a web application which accepts R code ,execute it and then place it in a neat way.

Comment: RStudio Server?

Comment: Do you mean something like [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) *lots* of ads, but it works in a pinch when you don't have access to a machine with R and you want to do something possible with base R.

Comment: http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/ sounds like what you want/is a possibility ... ?  (Although it's very old and looks like it might be broken ... but you could contact the author ...)

Comment: @AnandaMahto: post as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker, done. Wasn't really sure what the OP was looking for with their question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few possibilities come to mind:

- [ideone](http://ideone.com) provides a lot of different languages, of which, R is one of them. When you run a script, you are provided with a link that you can embed in a webpage (but which doesn't show the output, unfortunately). If you create an account, you can also store your previously run scripts.

  - Pro: You can easily insert `/plain/` into your script and be able to get a URL that can be sourced directly in R. For example, if the URL for your script online is "http://ideone.com/PIkeD", then you can use `source("http://ideone.com/plain/PIkeD")` to load your script directly from the ideone servers.
  - Cons: <s>Stuck at version 2.11</s> Might not always be the most current version of R. Presently at 3.2.2. Can't install other packages. Output doesn't show in the embed script provided.
- [Cloudstat console](http://alpha.kloudstat.com/index.php?do=/console/) runs a more recent version of R (2.15.1) with quite a few commonly used package. It *used* to have a really interesting blog/notebook interface that integrated code and the output, but that doesn't seem to be available at the moment.

  - Pro: Useful for running something fairly straightforward in a pinch.
  - Cons: Can't install other packages. Output is not formatted in code blocks, so is not easily readable. At the moment, can't save or share the code you've run.

[Crunch](http://crunch.kmi.open.ac.uk/) offers a full RStudio setup, runs the most recent version of R, and allows you to install the packages you need. This may be more convenient than having to install your own RStudio server. You do have to request an account though.

- Pros: Pretty much all you would expect from R/RStudio. Allows you to use Sweave and R markdown to automatically create documents too. These documents can be publicly hosted too. Here's an example where I've placed a page in a public folder called "gallery": http://crunch.kmi.open.ac.uk/people/~mrdwab/gallery/howzat.html
- Cons: Sometimes the loading time is a bit slow, but as I am running RStudio desktop, I don't know how Crunch compares to running my own RStudio server.

---

#### Updated January 10, 2014

Recently, there has also been a decent amount of buzz around [R-Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/) as an interesting way to share R code. It looks like it is what powers the awesome http://www.rdocumentation.org/ site.

Comment: Note that the Cloudstat link doesn't seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio IDE (Server) may be the answer to your question. Have a look at http://www.rstudio.com/ide/

Comment: Wow, just tried this. It's incredibly easy to install (three bash commands: apt-get install gdebi; wget rstudio.deb; gdebi rstudio.deb). Do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Rcloud which we are developing in AT&T research lab. Its a open source IDE like Rstudio/IPYthon and has more advanced capabilities in terms of collaboration. 
https://github.com/att/rcloud

RCloud is an environment for collaboratively creating and sharing data analysis scripts. RCloud lets you mix analysis code in R, HTML5, Markdown, Python, and others. Much like Sage, iPython notebooks and Mathematica, RCloud provides a notebook interface that lets you easily record a session and annotate it with text, equations, and supporting images.