# Get Twitter @Username with Regex in R

Tags: regex, r, twitter

How can I use regex in R to extract Twitter usernames from a string of text?

I've tried

```
library(stringr)

theString <- '@foobar Foobar! and @foo (@bar) but not foo@bar.com'

str_extract_all(string=theString,pattern='(?:^|(?:[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)')
```

But I end up with `@foobar`, `@foo` and `(@bar` which contains an unwanted parenthesis.

How can I get just `@foobar`, `@foo` and `@bar` as output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one method that works in `R`:

```
theString <- '@foobar Foobar! and @foo (@bar) but not foo@bar.com'
theString1 <- unlist(strsplit(theString, " "))
regex <- "(^|[^@\\w])@(\\w{1,15})\\b"
idx <- grep(regex, theString1, perl = T)
theString1[idx]
[1] "@foobar" "@foo"    "(@bar)"
```

If you want to use @Jerry's answer in `R`:

```
regex <- "@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_]*\\.)"
idx <- grep(regex, theString1, perl = T)
theString1[idx]
[1] "@foobar" "@foo"    "(@bar)"
```

Both of these methods include the parenthesis that you don't want, however.

**UPDATE** This will get to you start-to-finish with no parentheses or any other kind of punctuation (except underscores, since they're allowed in usernames)

```
theString <- '@foobar Foobar! and @fo_o (@bar) but not foo@bar.com'
theString1 <- unlist(strsplit(theString, " "))
regex1 <- "(^|[^@\\w])@(\\w{1,15})\\b" # get strings with @
regex2 <- "[^[:alnum:]@_]"             # remove all punctuation except _ and @
users <- gsub(regex2, "", theString1[grep(regex1, theString1, perl = T)])
users

[1] "@foobar" "@fo_o"   "@bar"
```

Comment: +1 It's good to know that the regex was not invalid, although the lookahead doesn't consume characters and the match starting at `@` shouldn't be grabbing the `(` with it. =/ And I'm bummed that I can't get a testing environment >_<

Comment: Yes `R` has a few unique details with regex... A few options for testing `R` on the web are here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13716528/1036500 [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) is my favourite for quick things like this

Comment: I tried using Ideone but it wasn't able to find the lib `stringr`... otherwise, I'd be able to test it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I think it only runs base `R` and doesn't install packages or make any kind of network connections.

Comment: @Ben  This is a great solution. However, if two username are next to each other. for example `@John@Ben`. You solution does not work. Do you know how to make it work in that case?

Answer (score 2):

`@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,15}`

Where:

- `@` matches the character `@` literally (case sensitive).
- `[a-zA-Z0-15]` match a single character present in the list
- `{0,15}` Quantifier matches between 0 and 15 times, as many times as
  possible, giving back as needed

It is working fine on selecting twitter usernames from a mixed dataset.

Comment: Did you test with OP example string: `'@foobar Foobar! and @foo (@bar) but not foo@bar.com'`?

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing out going back to the console

Answer (score 1):

Try using a negative lookbehind so that characters are not consumed in your match:

```
(?:^|(?<![-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)
      ^^^
```

EDIT: Since it seems lookbehinds don't work in R (I found somewhere here that lookbehinds worked on R, but apparently not...), try this one:

```
@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_]*\\.)
```

Edit: double escaped the dot

EDITv3... : Try turning on PCRE:

```
str_extract_all(string=theString,perl("(?:^|(?<![-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)")
```

Comment: Had to change `?<!` to `?:!` to make it work. It gets the first username but none of the others, which is what the function `str_extract_all()` is supposed to do.

Comment: R gives `Error in gregexpr("(?:^|(?<![-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)",  : 
  invalid regular expression '(?:^|(?<![-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)', reason 'Invalid regexp'` when I use `<` instead of `:`.

Comment: @Chernoff Huh, I was pretty sure R supported lookbehinds. If that's so, depending on what type of things you have, you can use `@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_]*\.)`. This will work on your example and checks for the `.` appearing just after `bar` for the last `@`.

Comment: I don't think R likes `\.`, I got the message: `Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_]*\."`

Comment: I submitted `str_extract_all(string=html,pattern='@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_]*\\.)')` but still no luck: `Error: invalid regular expression '@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_]*\.)', reason 'Invalid regexp'`.

Comment: To get lookbehinds make sure to specify `perl=TRUE` if you're using the base regex functions.

Comment: Thanks Dason. Seems like this should do it. @Chernoff updated my answer.

Comment: @Jerry got the message `Error in str_extract_all(string = theString, pattern = "(?:^|(?<![-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)",  : 
  unused argument(s) (perl = TRUE)` after submitting `str_extract_all(string=theString,pattern="(?:^|(?<![-a-zA-Z0-9_]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)", perl = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Chernoff Okay, seems like in str_extract_all, the perl option is activated differently. Try using the updated line?